# D3.js: end-of-line labels for lines of various length

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I have data consisting of a series of values that I load as such:

```
vars = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== 'round'; });
color.domain(vars);

var seasons = vars.map(function(name) {
    return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
            return { round: d.round, position: +d[name] };
        })
    };
});
```

I then do the following to draw a line per series:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return d.position !== 0; })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.round); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.position); })
    .interpolate('linear');

var season = svg.selectAll('.season')
    .data(seasons)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'seasons');

var lines = season.append('path')
    .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "season" + i + " line"; })
    .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style('stroke', function(d) { return color(d.name); })
    .on('click', function(d,i) { highlight(d, i, this); });
```

As apparent, I have zero-values in my data that I don't want to plot, which is why I used the defined function for the line. However, I later want to add a label with the final data value per series at the end of the corresponding line, I get some issues. For the series ending with a zero-value, this label ends up showing the zero-value in the position where the line would end if the zero-value were included.

```
season.append('text')
    .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.round) + "," + y(d.value.position) + ")"; })
    .attr('dy', '.2em')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .text(function(d) { return d.value.position; });
```

Anyone has any idea how I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no idiomatic way to do this, but you can just search for the first non-zero value, starting from the end of the array:

```
season.append('text')
  .datum(function(d) {
    var j = d.values.length - 1;
    while(d.values[j].position == 0 && j > 0) { j--; }
    return {name: d.name, value: d.values[j]};
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.value.round) + "," + y(d.value.position) + ")";
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I had just figured out myself that that's what I needed to do, but I wasn't sure how to go about doing it. Note that the while loop should be `while (d.values[j].position == 0 && j > 0)`.